# Version not changed after updating PostgreSQL on CentOS

Tags: postgresql, update, centos

**Actual OS and PostgreSQL versions:**

CentOS 7.3, PostgreSQL 10.1 to be updated to 10.2.

**STEPS:**

---

**Stopping the service**:

```
/bin/systemctl stop postgresql-10.service
```

**Checking available package updates:**

```
yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.ca.planethoster.net
 * extras: muug.ca
 * updates: muug.ca

libgudev1.x86_64                                                                            219-42.el7_4.7                                                                        updates
pgdg-centos10.noarch                                                                        10-2                                                                                  pgdg10-updates-testing
systemd.x86_64                                                                              219-42.el7_4.7                                                                        updates
systemd-libs.x86_64                                                                         219-42.el7_4.7                                                                        updates
systemd-sysv.x86_64                                                                         219-42.el7_4.7                                                                        updates
```

**Updating PostgreSQL:**

```
yum update pgdg-centos10.noarch
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror2.evolution-host.com
     * extras: muug.ca
     * updates: muug.ca
    Resolving Dependencies
    --> Running transaction check
    ---> Package pgdg-centos10.noarch 0:10-1 will be updated
    ---> Package pgdg-centos10.noarch 0:10-2 will be an update
    --> Finished Dependency Resolution

    Dependencies Resolved

    ========================================================================================================================================================================================================
     Package                                           Arch                                       Version                                  Repository                                                  Size
    ========================================================================================================================================================================================================
    Updating:
     pgdg-centos10                                     noarch                                     10-2                                     pgdg10-updates-testing                                     4.6 k

    Transaction Summary
    ========================================================================================================================================================================================================
    Upgrade  1 Package

    Total download size: 4.6 k
    Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
    Downloading packages:
    Delta RPMs disabled because /usr/bin/applydeltarpm not installed.
    pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                                    | 4.6 kB  00:00:03
    Running transaction check
    Running transaction test
    Transaction test succeeded
    Running transaction
      Updating   : pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch                                                                                                                                                            1/2
      Cleanup    : pgdg-centos10-10-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                            2/2
      Verifying  : pgdg-centos10-10-2.noarch                                                                                                                                                            1/2
      Verifying  : pgdg-centos10-10-1.noarch                                                                                                                                                            2/2

    Updated:
      pgdg-centos10.noarch 0:10-2

    Complete!
```

**Restarting the service:**

```
/bin/systemctl start postgresql-10.service
```

**Checking the version:**

```
psql -U myuser -d mydb -c "SELECT version()"
Password for user myuser:
                                                 version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

Still at 10.1. Any explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yum update pgdg-centos10.noarch` only updates the repository definition.

To update the actual Postgres binaries, you need to use

```
yum update postgresql10
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this the reason why yum check-update now shows packages it did not at its previous invocation? postgresql10.x86_64, postgresql10-libs.x86_64, postgresql10-server.x86_64.

Comment: In any case, after running yum update postgresql10, it works, version is now 10.2!